# Removing agent when resourcepool capacity reduced

Tags: anylogic

If I add a slider to control a resourcepool capacity, increasing the slider adds the resource to the population. However, how do I delete resources from the population when i decrease the slider? And what will be the delete order be? (From last added agent?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To destroy them, simply the the property "when capacity decreases" as below:
[image]

To test the sequence of destruction, run a few tests by addinga traceln command in the "on destroy unit" code box in the resource pool properties. It probably first destroys idle units but maybe simply destroys the oldest.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Can I follow up on this question? I am using these resources to build an equipment layout within a rectangular node zone. So when i decrease the resource quantity, the first few rows of the resources are deleted from the layout. However, after i increase the quantity again, the new resources are built from the last row, leaving the first few rows empty. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Hey, happy to help. However, on SOF you always ask new questions, it does not work like a forum. See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Alrights thank you so much! I'll open a new thread for this question :) appreciate your advice!