# Resource layout creation in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am using creating my equipments as resourcepools which are created within a rectangular node as a zoning region. During the model run I will increase or decrease the equipment quantity using a slider. I have set the settings to destroy the units when capacity is reduced (as guided in this thread [Removing agent when resourcepool capacity reduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751142/removing-agent-when-resourcepool-capacity-reduced/73752789?noredirect=1#comment130235877_73752789)). However, after reducing the capacity, the first few rows of resources are destroyed and when the capacity is increased again, new equipments are built from the last row within the node, leaving the first few rows permanently empty. How can I rearrange the layout to always fill up the empty regions first?

[image: Initial Layout][image: Reduced capacity removes first few rows][image: Increase capacity adds new rows from last row]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take control of positioning the agents yourself. Use the "on unit creation"  code box to 'unit.setXY(...)'  and position them where needed. Note that AnyLogic does also not care about positioning agents on top of each other. So if you want to have a concept of "this space is taken" you need to model that explicitly as well, best via a custom agent type itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will work on this approach!

Comment: cool. If you have follow-up questions, feel free to ask (but open new issues for each, some guidance here: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: thanks Benjamin! tried your method and it works perfectly :) will also take note of the questioning guidelines on StackOverflow :D

Comment: glad to hear, good stuff :)